# SoftLayer API: how to create a ticket

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a SoftLayer ticket on behalf of customers, want to set assignedUserId and assignedEmployeeId, make the first update by employee id.

I tried to use `client['Ticket'].createStandardTicket`, but  assignedEmployeeId was not set properly. Do you know how to get this implemented? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won’t be able to  assign an employee id since this parameter isn’t available in: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_ticket http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/createStandardTicket 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/createAdministrativeTicket

This kind of tasks are managed by employees and it is an internal subject.